# EF Core don't fetch data from database on twice time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I working with .NET Core 3.1 and EF Core 3.1. I wrote a method to fetch one row from a SQL Server database by its `Id`.

My problem is that when I fetch data for the first time, it is OK, but when I fetch that same data again, for the second time, the data is not fetched properly and returns `a` variable data instead of the database row (please see the comments in my code).

```
public async Task<AcademyStudent> GetItemAsync(Guid id)
{
    var a = await _context.AcademiesStudents
                          .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

    // the value of property a.Mobile is "09123456789"

    // change Mobile property with other data
    a.Mobile = "0000";

    // fetch again data from db with same query
    var b = await _context.AcademiesStudents
                          .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

    // but the value of b.Mobile is not "09123456789" but also is "0000". why!??? :(

    return b;
}
```

Where is my problem? And how solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because Entity Framework tracks the entities and it's changes. So once you load something into the context, it will return that.

You need to use `.AsNoTracking()` on the query

```
await _context.AcademiesStudents
              .AsQueryable()
              .AsNoTracking()
              .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
```

Comment: I am a bit late I guess ;)

Answer (score 2):

a and b refers to the same data object. Add `AsNoTracking()` efcore to prevent tracing  state changes.

I wouldn't recommend hitting DB twice anyway. If that is not just for test purposes, I think you need to consider your implementation logic as well.

Comment: Don't worry, still the right answer it deserves an upvote

Answer (score 1):

Firstly:

```
// change Mobile property with other data
a.Mobile = "0000";
```

Doesn't do anything on its own. You have to write the changes into the database by calling the write or update function of your context.

Secondly:

```
    var b = await _context.AcademiesStudents
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
```

does exactly the same thing as

```
    var a = await _context.AcademiesStudents
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
```

Because the lambda expression means: "Use *Id* to find an object with that Id and put it into *a*.
If you want to query a different object you have to query for a different Id.

HTH